# When are the results for Texas's early primaries published?

Tags: united-states, primaries, democratic-primary, texas

I live in Texas. I just voted in the primary. When are these results published? Do they get published daily? Do they get published before the primary at all? Do we wait until the primary results to see them?

Comment: DV, the OP has obviously made no attempt to research this Q

Comment: While the lack of research justifies a downvote, I do not see any reason to close this post. The existing answer clearly shows that the question can be answered.

Comment: There is no duty to do research outside of checking for duplicates before asking an on topic question. However, greeting people with the assumption that they did not research is a violation of the CoC to assume good faith. Truth be told, I did research. Sorry for not finding Chapter 65.015(a) of the Texas Election Code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No primary results will be released before polls close on Super Tuesday.

Under [Chapter 65.015(a) of the Texas Election Code](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/EL/htm/EL.65.htm) (emphasis mine):

> Subject to Subsection (b), **after the polls close and the last voter has voted**, the presiding judge may announce the status of the vote count from time to time.